# Problem Create dynamic list week per month on PHP

Tags: php, laravel

i have function PHP for get list week per month (Dynamic), but my code is bugy.
If i test on November 2023, first week start on date 6 to 11. But realy first week must start on 1 to 4.

```
function getListWeekPerMonth($tahun, $bulan){
    $week_array = [];
    $count_week = 1;
    $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$tahun-$bulan-1"));
    //$end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$tahun-$bulan-t"));
    if (date("N", strtotime($start_date)) == 6) {
        // Jika tanggal 1 jatuh pada hari Sabtu, tetapkan minggu pertama ke 1-8
        $end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date . " + 7 days")); // Akhir minggu pertama pada tanggal 8
        $week_array[] = [
            'week_number' => $count_week,
            'start_date' => $start_date,
            'end_date' => $end_date,
            'start' => date("d", strtotime($start_date)),
            'end' => date("d", strtotime($end_date)),
        ];
        $count_week++;
        $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end_date . " + 1 day"));
    }

    while (date("m", strtotime($start_date)) == $bulan) {
        // Periksa jika hari pertama minggu adalah Senin (1)
        if (date("N", strtotime($start_date)) == 1) {
            $end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date . " + 5 days")); // Minggu sampai dengan Sabtu
            if (date("m", strtotime($end_date)) != $bulan) {
                $end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$tahun-$bulan-t"));
            }
            $week_array[] = [
                'week_number' => $count_week,
                'start_date' => $start_date,
                'end_date' => $end_date,
                'start' => date("d", strtotime($start_date)),
                'end' => date("d", strtotime($end_date)),
            ];
            $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end_date . " + 1 day"));
            $count_week++;
        } else {
            // Jika hari pertama minggu bukan Senin, maju ke hari Senin berikutnya
            $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date . " + 1 day"));
            while (date("N", strtotime($start_date)) != 1) {
                $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date . " + 1 day"));
            }
        }
    }
    // Perbarui end_date untuk minggu terakhir menjadi tanggal akhir bulan
    $week_array[count($week_array) - 1]['end_date'] = date("Y-m-t", strtotime("$tahun-$bulan"));
    $week_array[count($week_array) - 1]['end'] = date("t", strtotime("$tahun-$bulan"));
    return $week_array;
}
```

Please help me.

List Week on November 2023 must have output:

```
Week 1 [01 - 04]
Week 2 [06 - 11]
Week 3 [13 - 18]
Week 4 [20 - 25]
Week 5 [27 - 30]
```

Comment: _Explain_ your desired output, please. Why is there a "gap" of one day between each of them?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the wanted result correctly, it should contain the start and end days of each week in a month, where start is Monday (or the first of the month) and end is Saturday (or the last of the month).

With the tools PHP now has had for a long time (DateTime and DateTimeImmutable), I would suggest to switch to them:

```
function get_monday_to_saturday_weeks(int $year, int $month): array
{

  $weeks = [];

  $first_day_of_month = date_create_immutable("$year-$month-1");
  $first_monday_of_month = $first_day_of_month->modify('monday');
  $last_day_of_month = $first_day_of_month->modify('last day of');

  for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    if ($i === 0 && (int)$first_monday_of_month->format('d') > 2) {
      $start_date = $first_day_of_month;
    } else {
      $start_date = $first_monday_of_month->modify($i - 1 . ' weeks');
    }

    // Edit:
    if ($start_date > $last_day_of_month) {
      break;
    }

    $end_date = $start_date->modify('next saturday');
    if ($end_date > $last_day_of_month) {
      $end_date = $last_day_of_month;
    }
    $weeks[] = [
      'week_number' => $i + 1,
      'start_date'  => $start_date,
      'end_date'    => $end_date,
      'start'       => $start_date->format('d'),
      'end'         => $end_date->format('d')
    ];
    if ($end_date === $last_day_of_month) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return $weeks;

}

foreach (get_monday_to_saturday_weeks(2023, 11) as $week) {
  echo "Week {$week['week_number']} [{$week['start']} - {$week['end']}]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Week 1 [01 - 04]
Week 2 [06 - 11]
Week 3 [13 - 18]
Week 4 [20 - 25]
Week 5 [27 - 30]
```

Comment: Thanks @lucas.j, but if you try with this:
``` lang-php
foreach (get_monday_to_saturday_weeks(2023, 12) as $week) {
  echo "Week {$week['week_number']} [{$week['start']} - {$week['end']}]\n";
}
```
Output:
```
Week 1 [01 - 02]
Week 2 [04 - 09]
Week 3 [11 - 16]
Week 4 [18 - 23]
Week 5 [25 - 30]
Week 6 [01 - 31]
```

But should be result:
``
Week 1 [01 - 02]
Week 2 [04 - 09]
Week 3 [11 - 16]
Week 4 [18 - 23]
Week 5 [25 - 30]
``

Comment: @Muyana Added some code after calculating start_date to take that case into account.